# How to redirect https to http without any SSL Certificate

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, redirect, https

Is difficult to explain what I am seekig here.

I have a website that doesn't have SSL Certificates and I am using a page as a landing page for a Facebook Application.

My Problem is when someone is on a secure connection on facebook (https://) the iframe src is pointed to the same https URL of my landing page. this returns an error like this.

```
SSL connection error

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

How do I may users redirect to http or any workaround without installing SSL Certificates?

Comment: Unfortunately, the browser must establish a successful HTTPS connection with the server before you could redirect it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is really no way to do that: HTTPS relies on the SSL certificate being present and the SSL negotiation ocurring BEFORE any data is sent to the server. Therefore if there is no SSL cert then it won't even get to the point where you can send a redirect (as you are observing).

I'd suggest just buying the cheapest cert you can: GoDaddy has specials for $12.99 that I've used quite effectively for just this purpose (Facebook app SSL pages) and that you can have bought and ready in 15 minutes.

EDIT: Just use [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), as @xbakesx states in his comment. Completely free, no delay, accepted pretty much everywhere.

Comment: I'd go for the free StartSSL certs instead of GoDaddy

Comment: You can also look into https://letsencrypt.org/ for free certs too (bonus you can have them automatically renew).  I'm not a rep for them, just a fan.

Answer (score 4):

I found a nice solution today to have pages with HTTPS without having a certificate.

You can use cloudflare SSL: `Flexible`.
This way the SSL will be between client and cloudflare server, and between cloudflare and your server will not be secure.

**This option is only if you don't have sensitive data because the connection betweeen server and cloudflare is not encrypted**

This is how it looks:

[image]

Check here more: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-

Comment: You saved me but a very strange JS then 525 redirections happen, not sure it's very good for SEO ...

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Femi's comment, all Facebook Apps and Pages must support SSL from October 1st so one must prepare for it anyways.

Re: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/

Answer (score 2):

If you can't prevent the initial connect from happening with HTTPS, then you (and your server) are never part of the conversation. The only two options are 1) get an SSL certificate (they are cheap), or 2) somehow get the connection to happen over HTTP.

Comment: Somehow get the connection to happen over HTTP, how? Redirect with htaccess or anything else?

Comment: @JustinJohn: Read the various answers again. The fundamental problem is that without the SSL certificate in place, no decryption is possible and *no connection* (of any kind at all) will happen. Without that connection, no code will run and no `.htaccess` file will be looked at. Game Over. See jupaju's answer for FB policy on this.

Comment: Then, Can you please strike off second option. When I saw it, it make me to hope that something can be done even after I read other answers. ;-)

Comment: No, it *is* an option *if* you can get the other site to cooperate and rewrite the link so it uses HTTP. Apparently in the case of FB it is not an option (which is a Good Thing®), but in the more general case there may be ways to get the other site to cooperate.