# Can I ignore/refuse https access to certain places of my heroku app?

Tags: https, heroku

I'm developing on Heroku a site with a couple of subdomains. One of them is signup (as in signup.myapp.com) which requires SSL access -- of course! But the rest of the subdomains, such as www, do not require https to access.

The problem is that the client only purchased an SSL certification for signup.myapp.com. This means that, when a user tries to access other places of my site with https (such as https://www.myapp.com), SSL certification does not validate and browsers tell the user that the site could be malicious... not good for branding.

I tried to make the site redirect from https to http, but of course this failed, because SSL was checked before the redirect could be sent.

Is there a way that I can deny access to these places of my site from https, so that users encounter, for instance, a 404 page instead? Or, do you know of any other ways to handle this situation? (the client is reticent to acquire a new SSL certificate, specially a wildcard certificate).

Comment: You don't mention what technology you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need a certificate for each of the domains (or a wildcard one as you mention), see e.g.:

- [How to redirect https to http without any SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331371/how-to-redirect-https-to-http-without-any-ssl-certificate)

The problem is that certificate is the first thing checked, way before anything else happens. If that fails, browser will typically display "get me out of here!"-kind of notification. There's no built in support for SSL-to-non-SSL transition.

You can shut down https://www.example.com (i.e. make your Web server not listen on port 443), but that of course won't yield a 404, also bad for branding.

With just one non-wildcard certificate, the only thing you can do is put all the pages under that domain. I.e. instead of https://signup.example.com/a/b/c, you need to do https://www.example.com/signup/a/b/c or something along those lines.

On the other hand, you can buy the certificate for under $100/year (or $150 total for 2 years) at GoDaddy:

- http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx

so, depending on your context, it might just pay off to pay this instead of doing any additional development.