# Lighttpd redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: lighttpd

I am testing with Lighttpd and I need to redirect all requests HTTPS to HTTP index page, because i not have HTTPS systema enabled.

I tried to use this:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    $HTTP["host"] == "." {
            url.redirect = ( "." => "http://%1" )
    }
}
```

but it not works for me... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect `https` requests to `http` unless you can establish a `https` connection in the first place. The first thing that is done when the connection is opened is attempt to establish the ssl connection, nothing can be sent.

This isn't a lighttpd error or a config error but a reality of the `https` connection.

Pretty much a duplicate of: [How to redirect https to http without any SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331371/how-to-redirect-https-to-http-without-any-ssl-certificate)