# Redirecting www to non-www while maintaining the protocol HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect www to non-www for both HTTP and HTTPS requests. My root .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

This isn't fully working as expected. What happens:

Visiting `http://www.example.com` results in a redirect to `http://example.com`. This indicates my first rule and condition are working, the mod_rewite module is hunky-dory and .htaccess is enabled OK.

Visiting `https://www.example.com` doesn't result in a redirect. I remain on `https://www.example.com`

**My question**

In order for the above rewrite rules to work, must my server have an SSL certificate? It currently doesn't and I'm wondering if that is the reason things aren't working.

Comment: Don't think you need both rules... You're only checking the `HTTP_HOST` for the presence of `www.`. It should work for HTTPS as well.

Comment: @MikeRockett Right but you need to explicitly add the protocol `http|https` to rewriterule target. I'm not sure whats the dynamic way to deal with this.

Comment: @MikeRockett yeah, the first rule's target is the problem with that. E.g. How do you avoid hard-coding the http or https part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule is taking precedence over `https` request because it simply met the rewrite condition. The first rule basically tells that match the domain and you can have your rewriterule to kick off. Instead add another condition which tells if its not `https` request

So try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You need ssl certificate for `https` protocol to work

Also I've added `[L]` flag which tells to not process further rules

Comment: The logic you describe sounds great but when I copy and paste into my .htaccess and request `https://www.example.com`, both rules fail. The first rule will be expected to fail but that second rule should work. Must I have a certificate in order for it to work?

Comment: @henrywright Ofcourse you need ssl certificate please read http://security.stackexchange.com/a/38592/35190

Comment: But should the _redirect_ still work without the certificate? I know I'll get the warning if I don't have a cert, but surely the redirect should still happen?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: @henrywright The redirect will work but the webpage won't be displayed because the certificate is not there to verify your host with the error `SSL connection error`

Comment: I'm aware of the warning because the certificate isn't in place. That part is fine. Totally expected. But, the actual redirect from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` isn't working for me. The non SSL redirect is working fine. e.g `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com`

Comment: Ah here we go. This answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6331410/1709033

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could try the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

# Check if the host contains "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.

# Check if we're using HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$

# Redirect accordingly
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Rahil Wazir's solution works when I test at a .htaccess checker such as http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. The problem is it doesn't work on my installation. I'm wondering why. My suspicion is I need an SSL certificate in order for the redirect to work but I can't find that out for sure?

Comment: Nice solution (+1), however, it can be simplified to just 1 condition. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313390/369434).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @MikeRockétt's answer, this is a "simplified" version, using just one condition (instead of three). This also canonicalises a FQDN (ie. by removing an optional trailing dot on the hostname):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.(.+?)\.?#(?:on(s)|)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This 301 redirects www to non-www while maintaining the same protocol, HTTP or HTTPS. Can be used unaltered in either `.htaccess` (*directory* context) or in the main server config / vhost. (Although, if you are in a *virtualhost* context you should probably be using a simpler mod_alias `Redirect` instead.)

#### Explanation:

- The *TestString* `%{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s` (which evaluates to a string of the form "www.example.com#ons") is compared against the *CondPattern* `^www\.(.+?)\.?#(?:on(s)|)`

  - The *condition* is successful for any request whose `Host` header starts "www.".
  - `^www\.(.+?)\.?` first checks that the `Host` starts with "www." (if not, it fails early) and *captures* the remaining host header (excluding an optional trailing dot) in the `%1` backreference. The regex that captures the domain name, ie. `(.+?)` is made non-greedy so that it does not capture the optional dot at the end.
  - `#` is just an arbitrary character that is used to separate the two values `HTTP_HOST` and `HTTPS`. Importantly, `#` cannot itself appear in either of these two values.
  - `(?:on(s)|)` is a non-capturing group that uses *alternation* to match against `%{HTTPS}s`. It either matches `on(s)` and captures the "s" (in the `%2` backreference) or it matches *anything* and captures nothing (so `%2` is empty).
- Providing the previous condition is successful then the *substitution* string (`http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI}`) is evaluated and the request redirected. The backreference `%2`, from the preceding *CondPattern*, either holds an "s" (to make "https" in the *substitution*) or is empty (ie. "http") and `%1` is the hostname less the "www." prefix.
- The `REQUEST_URI` server variable holds the full URL-path, including the slash prefix.

> must my server have an SSL certificate?

Yes, otherwise the *browser* will block the connection (complaining about an invalid security certificate) - or simply time-out (because your server is not responding on port 443) and the request will not even reach your server.