# Redirect BOTH http and www to https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The goal is to permanently redirect BOTH HTTP and www to `https://example.com` on a shared hosting service with an active SSL.

Several attempts; some involving a rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and other attempts involving, for example, rules like the StackOverflow post by Rahil Wazir involving:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L, R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L, R=301]
```

Thus far, no attempt has completely met the goal. Can you help?

Note that `https://www.example.com` should also permanently redirect to `https://example.com`.

Comment: "StackOverflow post by Rahil Wazir" - It looks like you are referring to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274372/369434)? But that relates to a different question with a different intent! In _that question_ they are not wanting to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, but maintain the _same scheme_ when canonicalising the www subdomain - which is indeed what those directives do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you are not implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (in which case you should implement two separate redirects, the first being HTTP to HTTPS *on the same host*) then you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (and www to non-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `HTTPS` server variable is an alternative (and arguably more readable) way of checking to see whether HTTPS is enabled or not, instead of explicitly checking the `SERVER_PORT`.

Note this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you have tested that it is working OK.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

Problems with the directives you posted:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
> ```

This only redirects HTTP to HTTPS. It won't canonicalise a request for `https://www.example.com/`. This is also a temporary (302) redirect.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L, R=301]
> ```

Apart from being syntactically invalid (you have a *space* inbetween the `RewriteRule` flags - which will result in a 500 Internal Server Error), this only redirects `www` *and* HTTP. But it redirects to HTTP, not HTTPS! Consequently, it won't canonicalise/redirect `http://example.com/` or `https://www.example.com`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L, R=301]
> ```

Again, the `RewriteRule` directive is syntactically invalid for the reason mentioned above. This only redirects `www` *and* HTTPS. Consequently, it won't canonicalise `http://example.com/` or `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: Thank you MrWhite - your solution works beautifully !