# old https causing issues in htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am redirecting my old site URL to a new site.

I have created a htaccess that redirects all old links (except root) to new path with added /shop/ directory. It all works fine but the old https is what all traffic is going to and it is throwing a certificate error becuase there is not SSL on the new server account.

Here is the current htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).(php|html)$ https://www.newsite.com/shop/$1.$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

~M

Comment: It is a bit unclear what your question is, but if you wish to redirect traffic to non-ssl new site, just replace `https` with `http` in RewriteRules

Comment: The old site was on https so all the current traffic going to it from google, backlinks etc.

The above htaccess works fine for http but if I follow an old link with https it throws the no SSL error.

I need to add code to the htaccess to redirect the https version of the old site to the new site, so it does not give the error and I do not lose any traffic.

Comment: So you are running oldsite.com and newsite.com on the same apache but have SSL certificate only for newsite.com?

Comment: yes, and because the old traffic is https it is giving an SSL certificate problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to solve your problem using .htaccess. You can not use HTTP rewrite to redirect from HTTPS to anywhere if you don't have working https site, since SSL certificate is needed for client and server to even begin to talk to each other using HTTPS.
You should create another virtual host for oldsite.com that will do the redirect (you should be able to get very cheap or even free SSL cert these days).

Other similar answers:

[How to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP without a certificate (Apache VirtualHosts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143210/how-to-redirect-https-requests-to-http-without-a-certificate-apache-virtualhost)

[How to redirect https to http without any SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331371/how-to-redirect-https-to-http-without-any-ssl-certificate)

https://serverfault.com/questions/429274/how-to-redirect-from-https-to-http-before-server-error

Comment: Is there no way to turn off https before other rules and conditions? I have seen this in another thread but this particular code did not work in my case.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

Comment: no, that is the main purpose of the SSL. The non-ssl request will never even reach .htaccess (or site at all) unless site is configured with valid certificate.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I made a typo in my last comment, it should be: The **ssl** request will never even reach .htaccess (or site at all) unless site is configured with valid certificate

Comment: gotcha. I fixed it. Just re-keyed the old SSL to the new server where the redirect resides and works great. :)