# Apache Redirect & HTTPS

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, virtualhost

I guess I am trying to do three things at once, but I am trying to:

- direct `example.com` to `example.com.au`
- direct `example.com.au` to `www.example.com.au`
- direct HTTP to HTTP

That is, four variations all directed to the HTTPS version.

Here are the sections in the configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com.au
    ServerAlias www.example.com.au example.com www.example.com
    ServerAdmin …
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com.au/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com.au:443
    ServerAlias example.com.au www.example.com example.com
    ServerAdmin …
    VirtualDocumentRoot /whatever/example.com/www
    CustomLog logs/example.log combined env=!dontlog

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com.au/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com.au/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com.au/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that although the redirection appears to be working, the certificate doesn’t seem to apply. When I attempt to open the following in my browser (without the `www`):

```
https://example.com.au/
```

I get the following message:

```
The certificate is only valid for www.example.com.au
```

Now I thought that the redirect should tell the browser that it’s really going to `https://www.example.com.au`, but:

- the address bar stays the same
- the certificate is invalid, presumably because the address bar stays the same

The question is: **How do I configure the virtual host to redirect these variations to SSL using the one certificate?**

My DNS server is properly set up (all names resolve correctly) and the LetsEncrypt is correct and current. Only the domain has been changed to protect the innocent.

Comment: Where/when do you see that error?

Comment: @DusanBajic I have amended the question. I forgot to mention that I get the message when I try to open the site without the `www`.

Comment: You will need the cert(s) for all domain names http://stackoverflow.com/a/37286822/1145196

Comment: @DusanBajic As far as I can see, that applies to `.htaccess`. Are you saying that the same applies to the `<VirtualHost>` configuration?

Comment: Yes. But since you are already using Let's encrypt certs, all you need is to split your `:443` VirtualHost into 4 separate vhosts, each with its own cert, and then configure 3 of them with redirection to `https://www.example.com.au/`

Comment: (btw, The reason for the warning is obvious: your browser, when trying to reach `https://example.com.au/`, can't trust that `301 Redirect` respond really came from `example.com.au`, since there is no such hostname in certificate)

Comment: I have learned a lot over the past day or so, and here is how I see it: HTTPS requires a valid certificate match _before_ the redirect gets to it, so the certificate must be valid for all the possible domains, not just the final one. I have also learned that I can save a lot of bother since LetsEncrypt can create certificates which match multiple domains (though not wildcards as such), I still only need one `<VirtualHost *:443>` block matching multiple `ServerAlias` values. @DusanBajic Can you put your comments in the form of an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the warning is: your browser, when trying to reach https://example.com.au/, can't trust that `301 Redirect` respond really came from `example.com.au`, since there is no such hostname in the certificate.

Since you are already using Let's encrypt certs, all you need is to split your `:443` VirtualHost into 4 separate vhosts, each with its own cert, and then configure 3 of them with redirection to https://www.example.com.au/ (or, if possible, get a cert that will match all needed hostnames).