# https://www.subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com redirect

Tags: redirect, iis, dns, iis-8

My boss wants to ensure that our internet-challenged users will be able to reach a particular subdomain (https://subdomain.domain.com) by typing it into their browser's address bar as:

https://www.subdomain.domain.com

It seems I am able to do the HTTP -> HTTPS redirect without issue using IIS's Rewrite module.  Also it seems I am able to do the WWW.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com with the rewrite module.  However, combining them is proving difficult.  So, it's when the user types in their browser https://www.subdomain.domain.com that ultimately fails with a privacy warning (our wildcard cert is for *.domain.com).

I've got a CNAME record set up pointing www.subdomain.domain.com to the A record for subdomain.domain.com.  I've got the bindings in IIS set up for each of the 4 combinations (with/without https, with/without www).

I have the following in the config for the site:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Still it seems that I can't get the browser to like the redirect from the https://www.subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com.  Why isn't the rewrite taking care of this before the browser attempts to serve www.subdomain.domain.com.  Is this even possible??

Comment: I wish downvoting folks would make some comment to help me better formulate the question.  If there is something I've left out, let me know what to add or how to change please!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is how to "https://www.subdomain.domain.com" to "https://subdomain.domain.com" redirect with IIS8.

Comment: You already know the answer:"when the user types in their browser `https://www.subdomain.domain.com` that ultimately fails with a privacy warning ", so you need the cert for `www.subdomain.domain.com`.

Comment: What I want is for the URL to be rewritten without the www, not to buy the cert for the subdomain (we have a wildcard cert).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37286822/1145196