# Apache 2.4 url rewriting with https

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do an url rewriting with Apache 2.4. I want that requests to

1. http://subdomain.domain.com
2. http://www.subdomain.domain.com
3. https://www.subdomain.domain.com

are remapped to

https://subdomain.domain.com

to avoid an error in SSL wildcard cert that doesn't not match www.subdomain.domain.com.

I tried with:

```
    <VirtualHost ip:80>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}       
   </VirtualHost>
   <VirtualHost ip:80>
        ServerName www.subdomain.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.com
   </VirtualHost>
   <VirtualHost ip:443>
        ServerName www.subdomain.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.com
   </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost ip:443>
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

My configuration works for (1) and (2) but not for (3). Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that one of your port 443 virtualhosts does not have SSL on.

Try this

```
<VirtualHost ip:443>
    ServerName www.subdomain.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /something
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /something
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise, the request simply won't be understood, because it's encrypted.

See eg [How to redirect https to http without any SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331371/how-to-redirect-https-to-http-without-any-ssl-certificate) for why this is necessary.

Comment: it don't works. Infact the request is understood from the browser that show that the SSL cert is not valid for that common name.

Comment: if that's what you're seeing already (before any changes), then maybe you have an apache config block higher in your config that matches *.subdomain.com. In other words, the config block in your question isn't being applied.

Comment: @drenda Please read the answer @Chris referred to. There is no way to respond (without warning) to `https://` request without the correct certificate, that is just how the protocol works.

Comment: @ChrisLear the configuration blocks are exaclty in the order I posted. The strange things is that when in the browser I see the alert of invalid certificate, I don't see any access log in apache. As if the request was blocked before arrive to Apache.

Comment: in your browser, when you ask to be shown the certificate, what does it show you? If you remove that stanza from your apache config and try again, what do you see now?

Comment: Showing the certificate I see the right certificate that match *.domain.com. Also removing that stanza I continue to see the warning about certificate

Comment: So that stanza isn't matching, which means that you must have another matching stanza somewhere, which takes priority. Because that stanza isn't matching, nothing you put there will have any effect.

Comment: It's possible that the stanza doesn't not match because the certificate is not valid for the domain www.subdomain.domain.com? I think it's that the problem. I haven't other stanza that match that url. Thanks

Comment: No, the question of whether the stanza matches or not is nothing to do with the certificate. Matching is done by `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`. If nothing matches, the very first block is the default. Check the spelling, and whether there's a wildcard in any of the `ServerAlias` values.

Comment: @ChrisLear but how can Apache go in the stanza if the certificate don't match the url? Is not blocked before arrive in the stanza? Is this what I mean.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think. You probably aren't using NameVirtualHost, and it's tricky making virtual hosts with SSL (http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts). Maybe just make www.subdomain.domain.com and alias in the `ServerName subdomain.domain.com` block, and put your redirect rule in there (which will then only occur if the user gets past the certificate error)